# getting linker error even after linking the core data.framework to my project target file

Tags: xcode, core-data, linker

I have linked the target file of my project to the coredata.framework in the Build Phases.
But still I am getting 3 linker errors like below:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CoreDataTableViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_RolesTableViewController in RolesTableViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CoreDataTableViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RolesTableViewController in RolesTableViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am getting this problem in 2 coredata examples i was following from the tutorials. I tried to find if i missed a step. I think I am doing some small fundamental error...

Please help, what it could be...

Comment: You're not linking the file which contain the definition of CoreDataTableViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this is solved now, but I had the same problem. When you copy the files to your project you need to ensure you put a check next to your project under "Add to targets".